# Different results for docker image ls using a wildcard

Tags: docker

I have several machines with Docker installed and I am trying to list/filter some Docker images like this:

```
docker image ls cdp-*
```

Some machines prints list of images, some machines (with same Docker 20.10.5 and same Docker images installed) do not return anything.
With Docker 20.10.6 I've even seen this error:

```
$ docker image ls cdp-*
"docker image ls" requires at most 1 argument.
See 'docker image ls --help'.

Usage:  docker image ls [OPTIONS] [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]

List images
```

What works for all machines is

```
docker image ls -f "reference=cdp-*"
```

Any idea why `docker image ls cdp-*` behaves so unexpectedly? I've tested it on different Debian and Ubuntu versions.

Comment: I've just tested your first command with docker 20.10.6 and got the correct result. Maybe you should try between quotes : `docker image ls "cdp-*"`. Anyway, according to the help, `-f` or `--filter` should be the official way to filter images.

Comment: @norbjd I think you've got it. I'll write the answer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it:

If there is a file starting with "*cdp-*" in the current directory, command `docker image ls cdp-*` fails.

If there is no file starting with "*cdp-*" in the current directory, command `docker image ls cdp-*` works correctly.

Comment: ...because your local shell expands `cdp-*` before the command is passed into Docker.